# Nuget and third party dll's

Tags: nuget

I'm confused as how to package third party dll's inside of a NuGet package.  I've created a nuspec file from my csproj.  This package's the csproj's output dll without a problem.  I then add a  element and add my 2 third party dll's.  This works and packs the dll's inside of the package.  I've installed the package in second project, but the only file copied to the bin is the output of the first project.

How do I get the dll's in the package's lib directory to be copied to the second project's bin?

I can't seem to find this answer anywhere.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls/64209711#64209711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried [nuget docs](http://docs.nuget.org/)

two great links:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/using-a-gui-to-build-packages
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package

Edit: quick reread tells me you may be having trouble getting dlls to include in your nuget package.  Remember in Visual Studio you have to set each file to build, adjust the settings in the properties for that file in VS.  You may have to make sure solution navigator/explorer is showing ALL files in order to do this.