# Create nuget package from dlls

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I want to create a NuGet package which adds multiple .dll files as references to my project.

I have a folder with 10 .dlls files in it.

When I install this via nuget, I want these files to be added to the project's references.

Comment: There is no magic tooling to automate that, and you have to learn .nuspec and pack up the assemblies that way.

Comment: @LexLi Wrong. See the accepted answer.

Comment: @Neo Both "NuGet Package Explorer" and "nuget spec/pack" use .nuspec implicitly. I wonder from where your comment comes from.

Comment: @LexLi NuGet Package Explorer is "magic tooling" that automates the process of creating a NuGet package containing DLLs, and then publishing it to NuGet. All you have to specify is which DLLs should be included, any meta data and the URL/key for publishing. This is what the OP wanted. I just did it today, and didn't even have to look at a .nuspec file once, and now have other projects referencing my package and including the requiring DLLs as desired. So I did not have to "learn .nuspec" like you suggested.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#advanced-extension-points-to-create-customized-package  this is what helped me for same problem

Answer (score 125, accepted):

> I want to create a nuget package which adds multiple .dll as references to my project.

I would like give you two solutions to achieve this:

First, Use **NuGet Package Explorer**：

1. Download the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer).
2. Open the NuGet Package Explorer, select the create a new package.
3. Add a lib folder on the content tab, and add your dlls file
4. Save the package and install it to the project, check if it add references.

[image: NuGet Package Explorer GUI]

Second, Just as Lex Li mention, We could **use .nuspec to pack up the assemblies**:

1. Download the [nuget.exe](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html).
2. Create a new project.
3. Open a cmd and switch path to nuget.exe
4. Use command line: `nuget spec "PathOfProject\TestDemo.csproj"`
5. Open the `TestDemo.csproj.nuspec` file and modify it and add the assemblies as file; below is my .nuspec file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <package>
     <metadata>
       <id>TestDemo</id>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
       <authors>Tester</authors>
       <owners>Tester</owners>
       <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
       <description>TestDemo</description>
       <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
       <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
       <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
     </metadata>
     <files>
       <file src="MultipleDll\*.*" target="lib\net461" />
     </files>
   </package>
   ```
6. Use pack command: `nuget pack TestDemo.csproj.nuspec`
7. Open the TestDemo package by NuGet Package Explorer.

[image: NuGet Package Explorer - built package output]

Comment: I am trying to make my first NuGet package and I learned about NuGet Package Explorer from you. Super easy.

One question: Do I need to put the DLLs inside a "native" subfolder of the lib folder? (your second screenshot suggest such a subfolder)

![screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Oxu1yFT).

Comment: @Mike If the ClassLibrary in this example has dependencies for instance to 4.6.1 you need to add the lib and add them dlls to the lib. Else you'll get dependency issues when installing the package later.

Comment: I'd suggest completing the installation steps mentioned on the [NuGet CLI reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference) to efficiently use nuget.exe in your environment. It's basically adding the path to the folder containing nuget.exe in the Path environment variable to be able to use it from anywhere on the system.

Answer (score 46):

I think the best way to create NuGet packages is use `nuget.exe`.

1. First, download and install nuget.exe (https://www.nuget.org/downloads)
2. Then go to your project folder, press <kbd>shift</kbd> + right click to display command prompt
3. In the command prompt, enter

   ```sh
   nuget spec
   ```
4. You will now have a `.nuspec` file. Open it in an editor and add Id, author, etc.
5. The most important part is the `files` tag after closed metadata tag.

   You can define all dlls here like this:

   ```xml
   <files>
      <file src="bin\Release\YourDll.dll" target="lib"></file>
   </files>
   ```
6. Finally, you can create `.nupkg` file with this command:

   ```sh
   nuget pack 'Your_nuspec_file_name'
   ```

This video on [**How to Create Nuget Packages**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KdnrRm8jTA) has a very useful and clear tutorial.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do it through Visual Studio or dotnet, then you can edit your csproj file, add an ItemGroup to include the dlls as below:
This will pack the other dlls along with your current project dll in the nuget package.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="<path to other dll>">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```