# Nuget package all sub project in a solution

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I have a solution which contains more than one Project. Project structure is as below.

```
/root
 A.sln
 A.nuspec
 /ProjectB
   projectB.csprj
   projectB.nuspec
 /ProjectC
   projectC.csprj
   projectC.nuspec
```

I have a few question.

1- What happens if I run `nuget pack A.nuspec` in root folder. Is there a way package all Project in a solution.

2- When I send the code TFS, with "NuGet Packager" I can use a regex to packege all sub Project as shown below. Is there a way to use such a regex in local environment.

[image]

3- Is it possible to create a nupkg contain both sub Project.

4- Is it possible to create a nupkg contain more than one dll. Can I put all dependency of the Project into nupkg.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- What happens if I run nuget pack A.nuspec in root folder. Is there a way package all Project in a solution.

I don't believe there is a way to package all project in a solution by using .nupsec. That because the process of creating a package always begins with creating a .nuspec package manifest file that describes your package contents. This manifest drives the creation of the package as well as its usage when installed **into a project not solution**. And the ID and Version must be unique in the .nupsec, so we could not use the unique ID and Version to specify multiple projects.

> 2- When I send the code TFS, with "NuGet Packager" I can use a regex to packege all sub Project as shown below. Is there a way to use such a regex in local environment.

The answer is NO. I have test it on my local machine, the wildcard is treated as **Illegal characters** in the command line.

> 3- Is it possible to create a nupkg contain both sub Project.

If I understand you correctly, you mean the sub Project is reference project? If yes, the answer is yes. You can use the the option "`IncludeReferencedProjects`"  to include referenced projects either as dependencies or as part of the package. please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#pack) for detail.

> 4- Is it possible to create a nupkg contain more than one dll. Can I put all dependency of the Project into nupkg.

Of course you can. You can refer to [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls/43316056#43316056) which I have answered for more detail. If you want to put all dependencies of the Project into nupkg, you can use the `<dependencies>` to include all dependencies in the .nuspec.

```
    <dependencies>
       <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0" />
    </dependencies>
```