# Nuget returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found' - Package on local drive

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Trying to generate a Nuget Package from dll. One of our project is generating ConfigurationCore.dll and References of project assemblies given below

- Microsoft.CSharp
- Newtonsoft.Json
- Mak.Enums (Custom Nuget Package available on local Nuget Server)
- Mak.Operations (Custom Nuget Package available on local Nuget Server)
- PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, PresentationFramework.Aero
- System, System.Core, System.Data, System.Data.DataSetExtensions
- System.Drawing, System.IO.Compression, System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
- System.Net.Http, System.Runtime.Serialization, System.Web
- System.Xaml, System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq, WindowsBase

Using below ConfigurationCore.nuspec to generate Nuget Package

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
<metadata>
<id>ConfigurationCore</id>
<version>1.2.0</version>
<title>Configuration Core</title>
<authors>MAKK</authors>
<owners>IT Department</owners>
<requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
<description>ConfigurationCore contains core funcationality of Software</description>
<releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
<copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>

<dependencies>
  <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" />
</dependencies>
</metadata>
<files>
<file src="C:\Users\makk\source\repos\ConfigurationCore\bin\x86\Test\ConfigurationCore.dll" target="lib\net461" />
</files>
</package>
```

Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'ConfigurationCore.1.2.0' with respect to project 'NugetTest', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Gathering dependency information took 1.09 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'ConfigurationCore.1.2.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'ConfigurationCore.1.2.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'ConfigurationCore.1.2.0'
The V2 feed at 'http://builtsrv1:8080/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='ConfigurationCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.1513344
========== Finished ==========

Note: The Nuget package source is on local harddrive... Please advise to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are referencing a non existing link: `http://builtsrv1:8080/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='ConfigurationCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'`

**You are using a method inside url, which is invalid** and is the cause for the mistake:

```
             //this is an error
../nuget/FindPackagesById()?
```

fix the url, test it and try again,

Answer (score 20):

Update your Nuget package link.

Go to Project -> Manage Nuget Packages.

Now click on your package source settings.

Update Source Link to `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

[image: Screenshot of the example settings as explained above.]

Answer (score 6):

Your URL should end with **/nuget**

Example:
http://yourDomain.co/yourNuGetServer/nuget

Answer (score 4):

This is problem of bad connection in the NuGet package. Add the following link into the NuGet Package.
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Tha

Answer (score 2):

> Nuget returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found' - Package on local drive

1. Make sure the path in the `src="..."` is correct.

   Perhaps the path should be:

   **`...\ConfigurationCore\ConfigurationCore\...`** rather than **`...\ConfigurationCore\...`**.

   In short, make sure you can find the dll file base on that url.

   Note: Generally, we recommend using relative paths in url, like:

   `<file src="bin\x86\Test\ConfigurationCore.dll" target="lib\net461" />`
2. Update the version of `nuget.exe`.

   There is [an issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2443) on the nuget.exe 3.4.x, so please download [nuget.exe 3.5](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and above.

See [Create nuget package from dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls/43316056#43316056) for more detailed info.

**Update:**
Please following below steps to create the nuget package:

1. Download the [nuget.exe](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.4.1/nuget.exe), and set it on your local, for example, `D:\NuGetLocalFolder`.
2. Create a new project with project name "ConfigurationCore".
3. Open a cmd and switch to the path where nuget.exe was stored previously.
4. Use command line:

   ```
   nuget spec "C:\Users\<Username>\Source\repos\ConfigurationCore\ConfigurationCore\ConfigurationCore.csproj"
   ```

   [image]

   You will find the `.nuspec` be genererated, Do not close this CMD window.
5. Edit the `ConfigurationCore.csproj.nuspec` file and modify it,  below is my .nuspec file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <package >
     <metadata>
       <id>ConfigurationCore</id>
       <version>1.2.0</version>
       <title>Configuration Core</title>
       <authors>MAKK</authors>
       <owners>IT Department</owners>
       <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
       <description>ConfigurationCore contains core funcationality of Software</description>
       <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
       <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>

       <dependencies>
         <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" />
       </dependencies>
     </metadata>
     <files>
       <file src="C:\Users\Admin\Source\repos\ConfigurationCore\ConfigurationCore\bin\x86\Test\ConfigurationCore.dll" target="lib\net461" />
     </files>
   </package>
   ```
6. Save `ConfigurationCore.csproj.nuspec` file, and back to your CMD window, using pack command to generate the nuget package:

   [image]

   The package `ConfigurationCore.1.2.0.nupkg` was created into the folder where nuget.exe exists, `D:\NuGetLocalFolder`.

Comment: When I am using relative Path(bin\x86\Test\ConfigurationCore.dll), Nuget pack is throwing error like File not found.

Comment: Where is your `.nuspec` file? If you using this relative Path, you should set the `.nuspec` file in the project folder, in the same folder of `.csproj` file. Right click on your project not solution, select open folder in the file explorer. Set your `.nuspec` file here.

Comment: Again, the relative path depends on where your `.nuspec` file is located. You can follow the detailed steps in the second method in the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls/43316056#43316056

Comment: yes, nuget.exe & .nuspec are in same project folder... but still Nuget pack is throwing error like File not found...

Comment: @JosephCenk, I have updated my answer with some detailed steps, you can follow those steps to create nuget package, please check if that help you.

Comment: @JosephCenk, How about this issue now? Have you resolve this issue? If not, please let me know the latest status info.

Comment: Thanks for you support, issue has been solved... I just removed http://builtsrv1:8080/nuget & it worked...

Comment: @JosephCenk, I`m glad that you have resolved this issue. You could post your solution to a answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen because you are supplying a "nuget v3" url when only a "nuget v2" url is supported (in my case `apt-get` was giving me some ancient version of `nuget`). Typically a nuget source that supports v3 will also support v2, so if your url looks like

```
https://<something>/api/v3/index.json
```

try changing it to

```
https://<something>/api/v2
```