# Add build event to multiple projects without adding one by one

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

I have more than 100 projects in my solution, now I have to add a post-build event to most of projects to copy some unmanaged 3rd party assemblies into its $(TargetDir), but I have to add this post-build event to those projects one by one, which is not what I want. So I want to know if there is a way to resolve this issue without having to add event for most projects one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add build event to multiple projects without adding one by one

You can add the copy target into the `Directory.Build.props` file and set this `.props` in the solution directory. If a props file is called `Directory.Build.props` it will be automatically imported to into all projects in the directory hierarchy.

Below in my `Directory.Build.props`:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="CopySAssembly" AfterTargets="Build">
      <Message Text="YourCopyTask"></Message>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Alternatively, you can use nuget package to manage those unmanaged 3rd party assemblies, add this nuget package to the multiple projects should be very easy, using nuget package manager for solution:

[Create nuget package from dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls/43316056#43316056)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Leo thanks for your answer. Any chance you could elaborate on the XML you used? e.g. what is `CopySAssembly` and how did you know `Message` could be nested there: any documentation you could point to would be inordinately useful.