# Why doesn't Nuget package contain only referenced projects?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

I am able to replicate this scenario:

This is the structure of my . Net solution:

LibC - project
--references external Nuget package

LibB - project
---references LibC

LibA - project
--references LibB

When I pack LibA with includeReferenedProjects option, I can see LibB. How do I prevent nuget package/lib folder from containing LibC dll and external Nuget package? Those are internal to the solution.

Shouldn't LibA package only contain LibB dll?

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't Nuget package contain only referenced projects?

This is a known issue on Github [Issue 2897](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2897). But NuGet team are not planning to implement this feature at the current time.

As workaround for this issue, you can create a `.nupsec` only include the referenced project LinB dll:

Check: [Create nuget package from dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls/43316056#43316056)

If you do not want to create the `.nupsec` file, you can download NuGet Package Explorer from Microsoft store, then edit the package info, delete the LibC dll and remove the nuget dependency(Edit->Edit Metadata->Edit dependebcies)

Hope this helps.