# Facing build error with System.Net.IMAP4 in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, azure-devops

I have a C# project in my local and it is working perfectly in my local machine. When I try to build the same project through Azure DevOps it gives the following build error

> [error]d:\a\1\s\packages\System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0\System.Net.Imap4.sln.metaproj(0,0):
>   Error MSB3202: The project file
>   "d:\a\1\s\packages\System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0..\example\example.csproj"
>   was not found.
>   d:\a\1\s\packages\System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0\System.Net.Imap4.sln.metaproj
>   : error MSB3202: The project file
>   **> "d:\a\1\s\packages\System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0..\example\example.csproj"
>   was not found.**
>   [d:\a\1\s\packages\System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0\System.Net.Imap4.sln]
>   Project
>   "d:\a\1\s\packages\System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0\System.Net.Imap4.sln" (1) is
>   building
>   "d:\a\1\s\packages\System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0\System.Net.Imap4.csproj"

In the IMAP4 library, it specifically says that the following file was not found. When I added the package through *Nuget Package Manager* it installed perfectly but does not download the  mentioned file *example/example.csproj* in the *packages/System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0* folder.

**d:\a\1\s\packages\System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0\System.Net.Imap4.sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file "d:\a\1\s\packages\System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0..\example\example.csproj" was not found.**

**System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0 package structure**

[image: System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0 package structure]

**System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0/lib/net35** (inside the lib there are no files and it contains only net35 folder)
[image: System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0/lib/net35]

**System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0/properties**

[image: System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0/properties]

What I am missing here to build the project successfully?

*Note: I tried to view the hidden files also but the example.csproj file was not found.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build error resolved with the following changes.

1. Navigate to this folder path /../**System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0**

[image: System.Net.Imap4.0.1.0]

2. Open the **System.Net.Imap4.sln** file and remove or comment the *example/example.csproj* line from the file.
   [image]
3. Build the project
4. Build is successful

Comment: Ahah, Yes, this is the workaround for this issue, I used to use nuget, my first thought was to create a new nuget package instead of directly modifying the contents of the package. But this workaround requires you to modify the contents of your package locally each time. When you publish your package, you need to pay special attention to it.

Comment: Sure I will be attentive during the publish

Answer (score 1):

> Facing build error with System.Net.IMAP4 in Azure DevOps

This issue should comes from that nuget package. I have download that nuget package from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Imap4/), then I unzip it, I found that the package did not contain the file `example.csproj`:

[image]

So, this issue related to the package, I am not sure if you are the Owners/Authors of that package, if yes, you need to re-create that package.

In addition, I have a long time to use/support nuget. According to my experience, this package is not correct.  As we know, nuget:

> An essential tool for any modern development platform is a mechanism
>   through which developers can create, share, and consume useful code.
>   Often such code is bundled into "packages" that **contain compiled
>   code (as DLLs) along with other content needed in the projects that
>   consume these packages**.

But that package packaged the entire project, which is not the correct way, it should only include the dll files.

You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not the author of that **IMAP4** package. I do not have idea on the package re-creation. I could not remove the package since it is a mandatory one. How do I fix this one?

Comment: I opened the issue in Github also to notify the owner. 
[IMAP4 Issue](https://github.com/bizzehdee/System.Net.Imap4/issues/2)

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan, The best solution is ask author to update the package, but you could to know, that package was the product of six years ago and there was no activation record. So, I suggest that you need double check if that package is mandatory to you. If yes, you have to re-create it, the new package just need to include the .dll file, check my other thread how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls/43316056#43316056

Comment: Let me check that way, otherwise I have to search for the alternate on IMAP4. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan, No better idea, Why this package is mandatory to you? Are you use it to develop scripts? If yes, what do you need? The IMAP4 reference or all files in that packages? I need to know what you want to do with it, I can give you a better change plan.

Comment: With the IMAP4, I retrieve the email and verifying the *From, To, Subject, Body content.*