# Cannot see symbols from a new version of nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I created a nuget package from a dll following the steps in
[Create nuget package from dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls)

This is a new version of dll that we receive from vendor (TIBCO in this case, dll is TIBCO.EMS.dll).

Now I can import the nuget package in my csharp project. However the project does not see the namespace or any of the methods in the nuget.

Now I know that program is unable to see the symbols so long as my local cache has the previous version of the nuget.

Supporting observations on this-

1. If I rename the nuget to a different name, then my program can see the symbols. (cache is organized by nuget name)
2. If I delete the local cached nuget in .nuget/packages, my program can see the symbols.

None of these solutions is good in a large team environment and with automation and anyway this is not the expected nuget behavior.

Can someone give a clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing my local cache solved this problem. There must have something wrong in the cache, because now I have created multiple versions in my local cache and it is still ok