# What we have difference between dll and nuget packges in .NET Core framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, package, .net-4.8

Can we add dll in .NET Core recent version.

I want to integrate older version of .NET framework into latest .NET Core project.

Should I need to create nuget packages of old dll files?

Comment: We have no idea what you have or what you are trying to do. You need to give much more detail. Also, multiple misspellings make it very hard to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: how we can convert dll files into NuGet packages? in .Net  core recent projects

Comment: Do you want [Create nuget package from dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls) ?